# How do I “select Android SDK” in Android Studio?

Tags: android, sdk

I am totally new on android and i'm still learning so problem is that when i'm installing 
    android studio and then create new project so android studio required android SDK so i'm confused 
    about it. If anyone have idea about it so please share with me.

[image: Screenshot of android studio is attached]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK is needed by android studio to build your apps and run emulators.
So, just go ahead and install this SDK by clicking next and doing the same whenever asked to do so by the IDE. Android studio is still buggy, so whenever possible, don't change any settings, and just do what it recommends you to.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i don't have any SDK file so please share any reference for download SDK.

Comment: You don't have to do it separately, just press next, if it doesn't work, at right most of menu bar, there is this button to download the sdk. (A cube with down arrow)